# Use Apply over a matrix of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I have

```
F = {{f11,f21},{f12,f22}}; (*Could be larger*)
x = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}; (*Could be larger*)
```

I want to have a matrix `Fx` that is equal to matrix `F`, where every entry `fij` is

```
fij = fij[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]
```

I tried with `Apply` and `Map` but I can't get it right.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it -- here is one with `Apply` and `Map`: `Map[#1 @@ x &, F, {-1}]` .   (BTW, I voted to close.)

Comment: Avoid using user variables, which start with a capital letter.  E.g. avoid using F as variable name. Use f instead. Alternatively, if you absolutely have to use a capital F, use \[ScriptCapitalF] or \[DoubleStruckCapitalF] (look very pretty in MMA). Type them in by typing esc+scF+esc or esc+dsF+esc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find `Through` command useful:

```
Through /@ Through[F @@ x]
```

> ```
> {{f11[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5],   f21[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}, 
>  {f12[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5],   f22[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Function[f, f @@ x, Listable] @ F
```

Answer (score 3):

So we can conduct testing with matrices and vectors of various sizes, let's write some code that makes it convenient to generate data,

```
xvec = 
  With[{n = 4}, 
    Array[x, n] /. x[i_Integer] :> Symbol[StringJoin["x", ToString[i]]]]
```

> `{x1, x2, x3, x4}`

```
farr =
  With[{r = 2, c = 3}, 
    Array[f, {r, c}] /. 
     f[i_Integer, j_Integer] :> Symbol[StringJoin["f", ToString[i], ToString[j]]]]
```

> `{{f11, f12, f13}, {f21, f22, f23}}`

Now we map the pure function `# @@ xvec &` over the lowest level of `farr`.

```
Map[# @@ xvec &, farr, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {{f11[x1, x2, x3, x4], f12[x1, x2, x3, x4], f13[x1, x2, x3, x4]}, 
>  {f21[x1, x2, x3, x4], f22[x1, x2, x3, x4], f23[x1, x2, x3, x4]}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = {{f11, f21}, {f12, f22}};

x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
```

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
ComapApply[#, x] & /@ f
```

gives

```
{{f11[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], f21[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]},
 {f12[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], f22[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}}
```

With `Query`

```
Query[Apply /@ #] @ x & /@ f
```

Same result

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `Table`:

```
F = {{f11, f21}, {f12, f22}};
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};

Table[F[[i, j]] @@ x, {i, #}, {j, #}] &@Length@F

(*{{f11[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], f21[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}, 
   {f12[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], f22[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}}*)
```